# Yii2 GridView add summarytext

Tags: gridview, yii2

I want to add summarytext to table summary how to achieve this?

have search this [api](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-baselistview.html#$summaryOptions-detail) , but still can't undersand.

**MyView:**

```
 <div>
    <div class="bg-primary text-white">i want to this in summary text</div>
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $provider,
        'summaryOptions' => [
            'class' => 'bg-primary text-white',
        ],
        'columns' => [
            'id',
            'address',
            'email',
            [
                'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                'header' => 'button',
                'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'color:#337ab7'],
                'template' => '{update}{delete}',
                'buttons' => [
                'update' => function ($url,$model) {
                    $url = Url::to(['controller/update', 'id' => $model->id]);
                    return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>', $url, [
                                'title' => Yii::t('app', 'lead-update'),
                    ]);
                },
                'delete' => function ($url, $model) {
                    $url = Url::to(['controller/delete', 'id' => $model->id]);
                    return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>', $url, [
                                'title' => Yii::t('app', 'lead-delete'),
                    ]);
                }
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ]);
    ?>
</div>
```

Hope you guy can help me out Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assign the value you need  ad a var of build a function for retrive the value you need 
the assign to the footer the var (or the function) you need
and set showFooter = TRUE in your grid configuration

```
<?php 
  $mySummary ="i want to this in summary text";

  echo  GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $provider,
    'showFooter'=>TRUE,
    'summaryOptions' => [
        'class' => 'bg-primary text-white',
    ],
    'columns' => [
        'id',
        [
          'attribute' => 'address',
          'footer' => $mySummary,
        ]

        'email',
         .....
```

Answer (score 0):

I find what I want

```
'caption'=>'<h2>Javed</h2>',
'captionOptions' => [
       'class' => 'bg-primary text-white',
],
```